# Objective-c : How to pause audio when webview playing an audio

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, webview

I'm using Audio Streamer class to play an stream url. I have to pause audio when UIWebView plays an audio file like Sound cloud. I have tried with "MPMoviePlayerController" notifications to know when user starts playing audio file in UIWebView but none of the notification fired when user plays audio in UIWebView.

Comment: I think as when UIWebView loads the page or site then you could stop the play of music. Else according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) there is no way to know whether music is played or not.

Comment: I think loading a fake html to webview will do the trick, it will override the current content, and audio will stop.

Comment: @walle84: I have done in the same way, but When webview loads some other data(Which doesn't contain audio files) then my original audio has to be play in background but with your suggestion it's not possible. I have checked in iPod i.e I played a song in Music player and i opened safari , went to the same page (sound cloud) and selected a song , when i tapped on play button , Music player has stopped playing song. I would like to build my app in the same way.

Comment: Try dis method **allowsInlineMediaPlayback** and for detail goto [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/allowsInlineMediaPlayback). This might help you out. Rest I would look for another way. If you find out then let me know.

Comment: @walle84: I have already tried it, but no use.

Comment: I tried that on iPod and total agree that it is doing as you said ,and also it's same on iPhone. I think there might be some intercommunication between safari and player that is making it happen but no idea of how to do it in app as I went through documentation and net. Still if you find out a way pls do let me know.